# How to find the max number of an unique string element in a alphanumeric Array list in java

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, collections

I have list that has alphanumeric elements. I want to find the maximum number of each elements individually.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Collect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> alphaNumericList = new ArrayList<String>();
        alphaNumericList.add("Demo.23");
        alphaNumericList.add("Demo.1000");
        alphaNumericList.add("Demo.12");
        alphaNumericList.add("Demo.12");
        alphaNumericList.add("Test.01");
        alphaNumericList.add("Test.02");
        alphaNumericList.add("Test.100");
        alphaNumericList.add("Test.99");

        Collections.sort(alphaNumericList);
        System.out.println("Output "+Arrays.asList(alphaNumericList));

    }
```

I need filter only below values. For that I am sorting the list but it filters based on the string rather than int value. I want to achieve in an efficient way. Please suggest on this. 
Demo.1000 
Test.100

Output [[Demo.1000, Demo.12, Demo.12, Demo.23, Test.01, Test.02, Test.100, Test.99]]

Comment: post tha code plz

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your effort when asking a question. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use a Map to store the data. use your word as the key and the number as value. Replace the value with max number.

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary, your suggestion does not make any sense because the same key can only exist once in a map and the OP's sample data clearly show that your suggested keys would be "Demo" and "Test" here, each of them existing 4x. If you use a map, the keys must be unique. I am not even sure that if the key would be "Demo.23" and the value 23, there might be possible duplicates or not because the OP didn't say if duplicate values can occur or not.

Comment: The array-list is being sorted as string values.

Comment: @kriegaex Exactly one key can't exist more than once. the key will be same. We should update the value of this key only if a larger value is found. For ex. `key:value=Demo:23` Now for next data `Demo.1000`, the key will still be the same , just the value will be updated as 1000>23. So now `key:value=Demo:1000` Any issues ?

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary Storing into a map as key, value pair will surely help , based on the insertion order the Hash map value will be retained.  But I we have problem in sorting the elements in an order.

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary, but your proposed solution will lose information. Furthermore, even the full value "Demo.12" occurs twice in the sample data, which means there can be duplicate values even if you look at the full string.

Comment: @Augustinraj your question says `I want to find the maximum number of each elements individually.` It says you want maximum. But if you want to sort, Map will ofcourse not help.

Comment: @kriegaex You are correct. . The second sentence of the question says he wants to find maximum value and hence I proposed a map. Using Map is not going to help in sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a special `AlphaNumericList` type, wrapping the array list or whatever collection(s) you want to use internally, giving it a nice public interface to work with, or for the simplest case if you want to stick to the `ArrayList<String>`, just use a `Comparator` for `sort(..)`:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60482676;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public class Collect {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> alphaNumericList = Arrays.asList(
      "Demo.23", "Demo.1000", "Demo.12", "Demo.12",
      "Test.01", "Test.02", "Test.100", "Test.99"
    );

    Collections.sort(
      alphaNumericList,
      (o1, o2) ->
        ((Integer) parseInt(o1.split("[.]")[1])).compareTo(parseInt(o2.split("[.]")[1]))
    );
    System.out.println("Output " + alphaNumericList);
  }
}
```

This will yield the following console log:

```
Output [Test.01, Test.02, Demo.12, Demo.12, Demo.23, Test.99, Test.100, Demo.1000]
```

Please let me know if you don't understand lambda syntax. You can also use an anonymous class instead like in pre-8 versions of Java.

---

**Update 1:** If you want to refactor the one-line lambda for better readability, maybe you prefer this:

```java
    Collections.sort(
      alphaNumericList,
      (text1, text2) -> {
        Integer number1 = parseInt(text1.split("[.]")[1]);
        int number2 = parseInt(text2.split("[.]")[1]);
        return number1.compareTo(number2);
      }
    );
```

---

**Update 2:** If more than one dot "." character can occur in your strings, you need to get the numeric substring in a different way via regex match, still not complicated:

```java
    Collections.sort(
      alphaNumericList,
      (text1, text2) -> {
        Integer number1 = parseInt(text1.replaceFirst(".*[.]", ""));
        int number2 = parseInt(text2.replaceFirst(".*[.]", ""));
        return number1.compareTo(number2);
      }
    );
```

---

**Update 3:** I just noticed that for some weird reason you put the sorted list into another list via `Arrays.asList(alphaNumericList)` when printing. I have replaced that by just `alphaNumericList` in the code above and also updated the console log. Before the output was like `[[foo, bar, zot]]`, i.e. a nested list with one element.

Comment: It works now thank you. I am trying to understand the lambda function that's the new learning.Great!!

Comment: He just needs max value associated with each unique string in the list, no sorting is required for that. Also, your snippet is just sorting on basis of each unique string not solving the actual problem

Comment: The OP's own sample code clearly indicates that, no matter how ambiguous his explanation, his intent is to sort the collection. So I stuck with his approach with the minimal necessary change, i.e. an additional parameter for `Collections.sort` which he was using already.

Comment: **Update 3:** I just noticed that for some weird reason you put the sorted list into another list via `Arrays.asList(alphaNumericList)` when printing. I have replaced that by just `alphaNumericList` in the code above and also updated the console log.

Comment: **Update 4:** Because you seem to be a beginner in Java programming, I also updated my code in order to show you how to elegantly create a list via `Arrays.asList(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using stream and `toMap()` collector.

```
Map<String, Long> result = alphaNumericList.stream().collect(
       toMap(k -> k.split("\\.")[0], v -> Long.parseLong(v.split("\\.")[1]), maxBy(Long::compare)));
```

The `result` map will contain word part as a key and maximum number as a value of the map(in your example the map will contain `{Demo=1000, Test=100}`)

Answer (score 0):

Check below answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> alphaNumericList = new ArrayList<String>();
    alphaNumericList.add("Demo.23");
    alphaNumericList.add("Demo.1000");
    alphaNumericList.add("Demo.12");
    alphaNumericList.add("Demo.12");
    alphaNumericList.add("Test.01");
    alphaNumericList.add("Test.02");
    alphaNumericList.add("Test.100");
    alphaNumericList.add("Test.99");

    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String val : alphaNumericList) {
        String key = val.split("\\.")[0];
        Integer value = Integer.valueOf(val.split("\\.")[1]);

        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.get(key).add(value);
        } else {
            List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
            intList.add(value);
            map.put(key, intList);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        List<Integer> valueList = entry.getValue();
        Collections.sort(valueList, Collections.reverseOrder());
        System.out.print(entry.getKey() + "." + valueList.get(0) + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

a. Assuming there are string of type Demo. and Test. in your arraylist.
b. It should be trivial to filter out elements with String Demo. and then extract the max integer for same.
c. Same should be applicable for extracting out max number associated with Test.
Please check the following snippet of code to achieve the same.

```
 Set<String> uniqueString = alphaNumericList.stream().map(c->c.replaceAll("\\.[0-9]*","")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(String s:uniqueString){
      int max=  alphaNumericList.stream().filter(c -> c.startsWith(s+".")).map(c -> c.replaceAll(s+"\\.","")).map(c-> Integer.parseInt(c)).max(Integer::compare).get();
        map.put(s,max);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I purposely added period in Demo & Test. I thought of handling individual elements bu in real time it will difficult to use. What happens if new 100 different elements are added in the list. I want to be dynamic in our approach.

Comment: in that you can identify the different String in your list first and have them in seperate list. Then iterate over list and extract out max interger for each

Comment: relevant code snippet: Set<String> uniqueString = alphaNumericList.stream().map(c->c.replaceAll("\\.[0-9]*","")).collect(Collectors.toSet());